# Ubuntu path tries to execute from snap folder instead of /usr/bin/terraform

Tags: path, terraform, ubuntu-20.04

I've installed terraform using curl from terraform website as snap application is outdated.

After install path seems to try to go to snap folder instead of /usr/bin/terraform where I have installed it with "sudo apt-get installed terraform"

echo $PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Currently I face this problem:
[image]

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you said, this is an inside package snap Is But you with the package manager apt-get You installed it, that's why the program did not go in the right place. Naturally it should not have been installed But now we know that it is installed incorrectly, so when you call the command, it does not find it because it goes to the correct address, but your program is installed in the wrong address, so you have to use the package manager snap Use the switch if the program is old
--classic use

sudo snap install  --classic

Comment: Snap installed Terraform 0.11. That is why I went trough tipical installation for 0.14. I currently, as workaround, removed /snap/bin/ from PATH. But I would like to find the best possible solution for this.

Comment: Modify PATH and put the directory with 0.14 in front of `/snap/bin`. Do not remove `/snap/bin`.